# How to disable window hot keys

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am facing a problem with my new keyboard. With this keyboard if i press 'D' key then it show desktop.if i press 'R' key it shows run command. I think this is due to Hot Keys.I am using Window 7.

Can anyone let me know how to disable window's hot key or any other suggestion.

Thanks,

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?q=windows+key+stuck

Answer (score 3):

Tap your windows key (between left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left <kbd>Alt</kbd>) a few times.  Win+D is show desktop and Win+R is "Run" window.  Sounds like it's just "stuck", or perhaps the keyboard/keyboard supporting software has some key lock of some kind.